# Why are emails from Find My iPhone in the wrong locale/language?

Tags: internationalization, find-my-iphone

I'm a native English speaker and I can only understand English. For some reason, every email notification I get from the Find My iPhone service (such as a "locked" or "alarm" confirmation) is in French. At least, it looks like French. Before today I've never set my locale to anything other than English on my phone or iCloud.

I tried switching my locale on my iPhone 4 and on iCloud, but the email notifications from Find My iPhone are still in French.

Comment: are you the first owner of the device? have you tried disabling Find My iPhone on the iPhone and removing the app?

Comment: I'm not the first owner. No, I haven't tried disabling and uninstalling the app, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Neither disabling/re-enabling nor uninstalling/re-installing Find My iPhone had any effect.

Comment: my best guess is this is a bug in the Find my ... process.  It's possible that the owner who first registered the device with the service had French as a first language and that is carrying over.  I'd raise a ticket with Apple and see what you can find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to log in to https://appleid.apple.com/ and set my country/locale/language to "USA". Took me a little while to figure this out. :)